# Unable to connect to MySQL database using springboot?

Tags: java, mysql, spring, spring-boot, jdbc

I generated a few tables in MySQL workbench and connected them as a datasource in Intellij. From there, I auto-generated the entity-classes using the persistence tools offered by Intellij, everything is looking good. I'm not sure what is happening.. The big stack trace is posted below.

The main thing that sticks out is an error in the MySQL syntax, but I have specified the dialect and this is all auto-generated.

It looks like I have 3 tables and 2/3 get created. From the picture below, it's the `GOALS` table that is not getting created.. Interesting..

https://i.stack.imgur.com/xl7m4.jpg

### Application Properties

```
#Standard network settings
server.port = 7777

# H2
spring.h2.console.enabled=true
spring.h2.console.path=/h2

# Datasource
spring.datasource.url= jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/habicus
spring.datasource.username=root
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create-drop
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

When I run the server, I get the following:

#### Error:

```
org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL via JDBC Statement
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:67) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlString(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:440) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.applySqlStrings(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:424) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.createFromMetadata(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:315) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.performCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:166) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:135) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.SchemaCreatorImpl.doCreation(SchemaCreatorImpl.java:121) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.performDatabaseAction(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:155) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.process(SchemaManagementToolCoordinator.java:72) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.internal.SessionFactoryImpl.<init>(SessionFactoryImpl.java:312) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.build(SessionFactoryBuilderImpl.java:460) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:892) [hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(SpringHibernateJpaPersistenceProvider.java:57) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:365) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.buildNativeEntityManagerFactory(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:390) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:377) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:341) [spring-orm-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1761) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1698) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:579) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) [spring-beans-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1089) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:859) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.5.RELEASE.jar:5.0.5.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) ~[spring-boot-2.0.1.RELEASE.jar:2.0.1.RELEASE]
        at com.habicus.CoreApplication.main(CoreApplication.java:32) ~[main/:na]
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval varchar(255), label_color varchar(255), pledge_amount double precision,' at line 1
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) ~[na:1.8.0_151]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3491) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3423) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1936) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2060) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2536) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2465) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StatementImpl.execute(StatementImpl.java:734) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.6.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyStatement.execute(ProxyStatement.java:95) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyStatement.execute(HikariProxyStatement.java) ~[HikariCP-2.7.8.jar:na]
        at org.hibernate.tool.schema.internal.exec.GenerationTargetToDatabase.accept(GenerationTargetToDatabase.java:54) ~[hibernate-core-5.2.16.Final.jar:5.2.16.Final]
        ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Comment: `interval` is reverved word in MySQL. You should rename that column to avoid problems

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As your exception logs say that there is a SQL syntax exception near `interval ...`

> com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an
>   error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your
>   MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'interval
>   varchar(255), label_color varchar(255), pledge_amount double
>   precision,' at line 1

So, the `interval` is reserved in `MySql`. Use different column name. You can use `@Column` over the getter of your `interval` property.

```
@Column(name="myinterval")
public String getInterval(){
}
```